# How to dynamically create routes in AngularJS using JSON?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a JSON file which contains routing details of a page. How can I create **dynamic routes** for the Angular views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routes are defined through [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)'s API. And the providers are available during configuration phase only. It means, that when routes are configured you are not able to perform http requests to get data from server, like JSON files with route configs.

I may suggest you to convert your JSON file into angular constant.

```
// route.constants.js
angular
    .module('app')
    .constant('ROUTES', [
         {url: '/some-url', templateUrl: '/path/to/template.html', controller: 'MyCtrl'},
         ...
    ]);
```

Since constants are available during configuration phase you can inject `ROUTE` into `.config()`. And then you can iterate over items in `ROUTES` array and configure `$routeProvider`:

```
// route.config.js
angular
    .module('app')
    .config(['$routeProvider', 'ROUTES', function($routeProvider, ROUTES) {
        ROUTES.forEach(function(route) {
            $routeProvider.when(route.url, {
                 templateUrl: route.templateUrl,
                 controller: route.controller
            });
        });
    }])
```